Solve 2d heat equation using solve_ivp
I'm trying to solve the 2D heat equation using the finite difference method as a filtering technique for an image using the solve_ivp method. My code is shown which gives an error message "y0 must be 1-dimensional" which I don't understand why is that.
# Read an image 
im3 = imageio.imread('photo.jpg')
#find out the dimensions of the image
height3, width3, colours3 = im3.shape

#convert the image to a numpy array for easier mathematical use
nparray3 = np.asarray(im3)
#convert the image to its grayscle version
grayimg3 = color.rgb2gray(nparray3)

#add noise on the gray image: The result is the initial 
#condition of our system
noisygrayimg3 =     
grayimg3+1.5*np.random.rand(grayimg3.shape[0],grayimg3.shape[1])
#Reshape the initial conditions into a vector so it can be     
#passed into the ODE solver
U0 = np.reshape(noisygrayimg3, (width3*height3, 1)) 

#Define a grid of x and y variables and their derivatives
#x variable
x = np.linspace(0,1,width3) #patial vector
dx = x[1]-x[0] #spatial step size
onex = np.ones(width3)
Ix = np.eye(width3)
Dx = sp.spdiags([onex , -2*onex , onex], [-1, 0, 1], width3, 
width3) #x 1D matrix 
#y variable
y = np.linspace(0,1,height3) #patial vector
dy = y[1]-y[0] #spatial step size
oney = np.ones(height3)
Iy = np.eye(height3)
Dy = sp.spdiags([oney , -2*oney , oney], [-1, 0, 1], height, 
height3) #y 1D matrix 

#create the 2D Laplacian
A = sp.kron(Dx,Iy) + sp.kron(Ix,Dy) 

#Define the Diffusion coefficient
D = 0.005

#solve the diffusion equation
#STEP 1: define the function that returns du/dt which computes the 
right-hand side of the heat equation
def Diffusion_rhs(t,u):    
    #caluclate the right-hand side
    dudt = D * A* u
    return dudt

#STEP 2: define  the Time variable for the integration
tspan = np.array([0, 2])

#STEP 3: solve the system
sol = solve_ivp(Diffusion_rhs, tspan, U0)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

For simplicity of the implementation, the scipy solvers only allow flat arrays as state in the interface and their internal procedures. If your state is structured, then you need to apply suitable transformations in the ODE function, from array to structure at the start and from structure to array for the derivatives at the end for the return object. There exist reshape methods for numpy objects.
For the odeint method there exists the odeintw package that produces a wrapper for the ODE function from the structure of the initial state.
Other software packages allow structured objects that implement the basic vector operations. One example is the Julia ODE solver package, which can also be interfaced from python.
